# How to control speed of CSS animation not just duration time?

Tags: css, animation

I have a list of scrolling list items that uses a CSS animation keyframe. It does what I want it to, but I'm only controlling the time duration, not speed, so if I add items it goes too fast and if I take away items it goes too slow.

Is it possible to set a speed with just CSS?

Here is my CSS, a link to a CodePen: https://codepen.io/disco_p/pen/BvWdqX?editors=1100

```
section {
    height: 90vh;
    background: #000;
}

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: em(18);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    column-count: 4;
    column-width: 200px;
    column-gap: 50px;
    animation: floatTextUp 3s infinite linear;
  }

  li {
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
  }

  .scroll {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  @keyframes floatTextUp {
    to {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Short answer: no. Only with JS

Comment: you can't but, you can do something else, instead of using `to` use `0%` to `100%`, the items you want to move faster can be "done" at `50%` while the rest is set to the `100%`

Comment: @HerrSerker Thank you. Next question then: how would you handle this with JS?

Comment: You need to compute the total size (I suggest `outerHeight` in your case) and then compute the duration according to that result.